# Azure Emulator - Table Storage, works locally, but not on azure

Tags: c#, oauth, azure-storage, asp.net-web-api2

I have a weird scenario:

I'm trying to implement refresh tokens as outlined here:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

I've got it to work as the blog post has it, but now I've changed DB context for a custom cloud context so that all of the security tables are Azure Storage tables. The AuthRepository ends up being the same as the blog and essentially the OAuth stuff has 90% the same code (there are slight differences in the calls to the context).

When I point my webapi at my local Storage Emulator I can login and the refresh token is created and I can use the refresh token to get another access token. It all works. But when I point the webapi at actual Azure Storage I can no longer get a fresh token, I can login fine and the refresh token is created in table storage. It hits

`SimpleRefreshTokenProvider.ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)`

and finds the existing refreshToken, deserializes the ticket

`context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);`

and then removes the refreshToken from the table, but the only response I get from the webapi token endpoint ('/token') is {"error":"invalid_grant"}.

I really don't know where to start looking for this error as there is no exception throw (I've been stepping through all of my code) and `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)` is never called

I have:

- nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage 4.3.0
- Azure Storage Emulator 3.2.0.0

NB: Please forgive my lack of code, any direction on what to include is welcomed. I'm ready to edit!

Comment: Have you added the connection string under `Config>Connection Strings` in the Azure Management Portal?

Comment: If you mean in the website, then no, I'm running everything locally except I'm connecting to Azure Store and not my local emulator. Or I've miss understood what you're saying

Comment: I am also facing the same problem where ReceiveAsync method DeserializeTicket from AccessToken but not in RefreshToken with same SerializedTicket from database. If you have solved then please post solution.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did anyone find a solution to this?